# The connector between steps disappears when I set display .ant-steps-item-icon with flex

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, antd

I used ANTD and React and I want to customize the component step style, and I got this:
[image]

from the following CSS code:

```
/* step connector */
.ant-steps-item-title:after {
    border: solid rgba(65, 64, 66, 0.1) !important;
}

/* step */
.ant-steps-item-icon{
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    display: flex; // ==> when i add this
    justify-content: center; // ==> when i add this
    align-items: center; // ==> when i add this
}


.ant-steps-item-process > .ant-steps-item-container > .ant-steps-item-icon {
    background-color: #21D47E;
    border-color: #21D47E;

}

/* size of step container */
.ant-steps{
    width: 50%;

} 

.ant-steps-horizontal .ant-steps-label-horizontal{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

When I add this to centering the number:

```
.ant-steps-item-icon{
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    display: flex; *
    justify-content: center; *
    align-items: center; *
}
```

the steps connector is missing like this:
[image]

and this is my react component calling Steps:

```
import { Steps } from 'antd'
import React from 'react'
import './index.css'

const { Step } = Steps

export const Tahap: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '50px' }}>
      <Steps>
        <Step />
        <Step />
        <Step />
        <Step />
        <Step />
        <Step />
      </Steps>
    </div>
  )
}
```

can anyone tell me how to re-display the connector? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result, you need to use the `display` property with the `inline-flex` value instead of `flex`:

```
.ant-steps-item-icon {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It makes the flex container display inline.